# Assignable to type but could be instantiated with a different subtype

Tags: typescript, msw

I want to decorate an [MSW resolver](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/response-resolver#reusable-resolver) and return a new resolver using [response composition](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/custom-response-composition).

```
import {
  ResponseResolver,
  context,
  createResponseComposition,
  response
} from "msw";

export const createDelayedComposer = <
  M extends ResponseResolver<any, any, any>
>(
  milliseconds: number
) => {
  const delayed = createResponseComposition(undefined, [
    context.delay(milliseconds)
  ]);
  return (resolver: M): M => (req, _, ctx) =>
    resolver(req, Object.assign(delayed, response), ctx);
};
```

The error is:

```
Type '(req: any, _: ResponseComposition<any>, ctx: any) => AsyncResponseResolverReturnType<MockedResponse<any>>' is not assignable to type 'M'.
  '(req: any, _: ResponseComposition<any>, ctx: any) => AsyncResponseResolverReturnType<MockedResponse<any>>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'M', but 'M' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ResponseResolver<any, any, any>'.ts(2322)
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-kxs7xl?file=/index.ts:0-413)

I've read through similiar answers but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. What's wrong with my signature, and how to fix it?

Alternatively, maybe there's another way entirely to achieve the goal of decorating the resolver function

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this call signature.

### TL;DR

```
import { createResponseComposition, context } from 'msw'

export function resWithDelay() {
  
}

export const resWithDelay = createResponseComposition(undefined, [
  context.delay(500)
])
```

```
import { resWithDelay } from './resWithDelay'

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('/resource', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return resWithDelay(ctx.text('Hello world'))
  })
]
```

**Please note that the entire purpose of custom response composition is to encapsulate repetitive behavior.** In your original code, you imply that the delay duration is dynamic and as such there's no benefit of such a custom response composition, you are much better off using `ctx.delay()` on a per-response basis:

```js
rest.get('/resource', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(ctx.delay(500), ctx.text('One'))
}),
rest.post('/login', (req, res, ctx) => {
  return res(ctx.delay(250), ctx.text('One'))
})
```